# How to decide whether to read 「昨夜」 as 「さくや」 or「 ゆうべ」?

Tags: readings

I found [an answer saying that 「さくや」is the correct reading of 「昨夜」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/278/4623), but despite that I often encounter it as「ゆうべ」.

Is there a difference in meaning or are both readings interchangeable?

Comment: Maybe when talking you encounter 夕(べ) and not 昨夜？

Comment: Yes, but I also saw it in texts and example sentences where 昨夜 had ゆうべ as furigana.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are correct readings. It depends a lot on the context, but ゆうべ is informal and さくや is formal.

The same can be seen in 明日 with あす and あした, or in 昨日 with きのう and さくじつ.