# Difference among evening words 夕方, 夕べ, 晩, 夕?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I've found several words in the book, which means `evening`. What's the difference among them?

*I've found only this information:*

```
夕 - 5pm to 7pm
晩 - 7pm to 10pm
夜 - 10pm onwards (night, late evening)
```

But not sure, is it true and what's the difference among `夕方` and `夕べ` and the others?

Comment: As far as I know, 夕方 is used to convey early evening of any day, but 夕べ means specifically yesterdays's evening.

Comment: @jarmanso7 thank you for the information. What about 昨日の晩？It was represented in my student's book as "yesterday evening" too. What's the difference here? :)

Comment: I honestly do not know what the difference is based on my experience, but according to this answer, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/29008/32952, 昨夜 is more formal than 夕べ.

Comment: As for 夕, 晩 and 夜, I've heard that the difference between 夕 and 晩 is related to whether the sun has settled or not, and 夜 is simply night, not evening. But I am very unsure of this so we'd better to wait for somene's else answer on this.

Comment: @jarmanso7 thanks anyway. Will collect all the information in one.

Comment: FYI, 夕べ originally meant evening of any day (cf., German morgen “morning, tomorrow”). You can still see usages with the original meaning in event names like “音楽の夕べ.”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a Japanese Dictionary:

## 夕

> 日が沈んで夜になろうとする時。夕暮れ。夕方。ゆうべ。「朝に夕に故郷を思う」
>   https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%A4%95-546992

夕 means the time when the sun sets. But, 夕 is not used in modern Japanese. It is only seen in classical texts.

## 夕方

> 日の暮れがた。日の沈むころ。
>   https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%A4%95%E6%96%B9-650419

夕方 also means sun setting time, but 夕方 is used in modern Japanese.

Note that 夕方 has antonym: 明け方. 明け方 means sun rising time.

## 晩

This word has many meanings:

> 1. 夕暮れ。夕方。
> 2. 夜。
> 3. 晩飯。
>      https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%99%A9-605993

1. says `晩 is 夕方`, but 2. says `晩 is night`.

And so, 晩  (3. means 晩 is dinner) is used to express a wider span of time.

## 夕べ

> 1. 日の暮れるころ。夕方。「秋の夕べ」
> 2. 何かの催し物が行われる夜。「音楽の夕べ」
> 3. きのうの夜。さくや。昨晩。「夕べは飲み明かした」「夕べ地震があった」
>      https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%A4%95%E3%81%B9-651184

1. says `夕べ is 夕方`. 2. says `A night with some event`. 3. says `Last night`.

I think 2. is the most common usage and 3. is not used very often because the other word `昨晩`'s pronunciation is the same. However, because 夕べ also means 夕方, 昨晩 is preferred.

Note that 昨晩 has two ways of reading it: `yube` (same as 夕べ) and `sakuban`.

## Conclusion

夕方 and 夕 are almost the same, but 夕 is used only in a literary style. 晩 means a later time.

Comment: Thank you very much! And for the links to the dictionary

Comment: Pretty good but you missed 夜